# PHP converting sec to min

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have this php code that retrieve the time taken for a video to be converted using FFMPEG. however the output is in seconds. my maths fail me and i cant get it to display in minutes instead of seconds.

will appreciate any help.

```
            $content = @file_get_contents('logfile.txt');

            if($content){
            //get duration of source
            preg_match("/Duration: (.*?), start:/", $content, $matches);

            $rawDuration = $matches[1];

            //rawDuration is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
            $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawDuration));
            $duration = floatval($ar[0]);
            if (!empty($ar[1])) $duration += intval($ar[1]) * 60 ;
            if (!empty($ar[2])) $duration += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60 * 60;

            //get the time in the file that is already encoded
            preg_match_all("/time=(.*?) bitrate/", $content, $matches);

            $rawTime = array_pop($matches);

            //this is needed if there is more than one match
            if (is_array($rawTime)){$rawTime = array_pop($rawTime);}

            //rawTime is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
            $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawTime));
            $time = floatval($ar[0]);
            if (!empty($ar[1])) $time += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
            if (!empty($ar[2])) $time += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

            //calculate the progress
            $progress = round(($time/$duration) * 100);

            echo "Duration: " . $duration . "<br>";
            echo "Current Time: " . $time . "<br>";
            echo "Progress: " . $progress . "%";

}
```

Comment: 1 minute = 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$seconds = "150";
$minutes = floor($seconds/60);
$secondsleft = $seconds%60;
if($minutes<10)
    $minutes = "0" . $minutes;
if($secondsleft<10)
    $secondsleft = "0" . $secondsleft;
echo "$minutes:$secondsleft minutes";
?>
```

Comment: While this maybe can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.